# Enable ruff rules only on specific files

Tags: python, ruff

I work on a large project and I'd slowly like to enfore pydocstyle using ruff. However, many files will fail on e.g. D103 "undocumented public function". I'd like to start with enforcing it on a few specific files, so I'd like to write something like

```
select = ["D"]

[tool.ruff.ignore-except-per-file] # this config does not exist
# ignore D103 but on all files, except the ones that pass
"properly_formatted_module1.py" = ["D103"]
"properly_formatted_module2.py" = ["D103"]
```

I don't think this is possible; the only way I see is to explicitly write down ALL of the file names in a `[tool.ruff.extend-per-file-ignores]`. There are a few hunderd of them so that's not really nice to do.